# Unable to compile angular Type Inference error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
interface Course {
  name: string;
  lessonCount: number;
}
interface Named {
  name: string;
}

let named: Named = {
name: 'Name goes here'
};

let course: Course = {
name: 'Components and Directives',
lessonCount: 20
};

named = {name: 'dfdf'};
course =  {name: 'sfdsf', lessonCount: 25};

named = course;
course = named;
```

**named =  {name: 'sfdsf', lessonCount: 25};** why this is not getting compiled?

**named = course;**  //why this is getting compiled properly

Does above 2 lines NOT same??

I am very new to angular/typescript, please clear me on above. I am basically from Java background.

Comment: The answer is correct as @saivishnu states below, well to get a full closure of understanding you can read through this documentation of Interfaces in Typescript :
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Answer (score 1):

when you say

```
named = {name: 'sfdsf', lessonCount: 25};
```

the ts compiler thinks that you are trying to assign lesson count to a object with name named whose structure is defined by the interface named. so it sees that lesson count is not part of this structure and gives an error.

when you say

```
named = course
```

the ts compiler thinks that you are assigning a course object with structure of course to named object of structure named. it checks if such a assignment can be done. because there is a common element name in both it allows it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of an edge case in `TypeScript` and feels counter intuitive and hard to explain, but I'll try my best.

Let's start with this one

```
named = course;
```

This compiles fine, because the interface `Course` has a `name` property which is (required) `string`. That the interface and the object also have a `lessonCount`, is not interesting for the compiler. As long as the assigned type has all the properties given in the interface. 
The type of `named` will stay `Named`, and if you try to do `named.lessonCount` after assigning `course` to it, it will give an error. So for all intents and purposes, according to the compiler, `named` does not have a `.lessonCount` property, even though you know better. This is called Lenient type checking

Now if you do an `Object literal` assignment:

```
named = {name: 'sfdsf', lessonCount: 25};
```

The compiler says, hey! I see you are trying to assign this object literal to my `Named` interface, but you have defined a `lessonCount` property as well. I do not agree upon this.

According to the docs:

> However, TypeScript takes the stance that there’s probably a bug in this code. Object literals get special treatment and undergo excess property checking when assigning them to other variables, or passing them as arguments. If an object literal has any properties that the “target type” doesn’t have, you’ll get an error

On the other hand, this works again:

```
named = {name: 'sfdsf', lessonCount: 25} as Course;
```

This is also explained in detail [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)

> Notice that our object actually has more properties than this, but the compiler only checks that at least the ones required are present and match the types required.